# Xlookup VBA Worksheet Function on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I have 2 Sheets "DataEntry" & "Result". I am using Worksheet Function  Xlookup to display values in column G of the "Result" Sheet.
The lookup value is in column D of the "Result" Sheet
The lookup array is in column F of the "DataEntry" Sheet
The resulting array is in column I of the "DataEntry" Sheet
The VBA code I have used is as follows:

```
    Sub WorksheetFunctionsXlookupMacro()
    Dim shDataEntry As Worksheet
    Dim shResult As Worksheet
    Dim indx As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Set shDataEntry = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataEntry")
    Set shResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")
    lastRow = shResult.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For indx = 3 To lastRow

    shResult.Range("G" & indx).Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(shResult.Range("D" & indx).Value,     shDataEntry.Range("F6:F28"), shDataEntry.Range("I6:I28"))
    Next
    End Sub
```

I want to use Worksheet Function Xlookup for multiple criteria to display values in column G of the Result Sheet:

```
Lookup value1 is in column D of "Result" Sheet
Lookup value2 is in column E of "Result" Sheet
Lookup value3 is in column F of "Result" Sheet
Lookup array1 is in column F of "DataEntry" Sheet
Lookup array2 is in column G of "DataEntry" Sheet
Lookup array3 is in column H of "DataEntry" Sheet
Result array is in column I of "DataEntry" Sheet
```

Need VBA code for WorksheetFunction Xlookup to display result in column G of Result Sheet

Comment: Do you just want a xlookup function for multiple lookup criteria? or is it something else you want. it is not really clear in your post

Comment: need the Xlookup Workfunction code for x lookup with multiple criteria. I am able to get result when Xlookup is done with one criteria as shown in the vba code below: shResult.Range("G" & indx).Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(shResult.Range("D" & indx).Value,     shDataEntry.Range("F6:F28"), shDataEntry.Range("I6:I28"))